If there's magnetic field around current-carrying wire, why doesn't it always exist?
Motion is relative.
If we say train is moving, it moves with respect to the Earth. If we are inside, it doesn't move from our point of view.
Then, with respect to what object do we say that electrons have to move in order to produce magnetic field? With respect to positively charged particles? Why doesn't standing still wire produce magnetic field? Or does it but it cancels out? Maybe magnets are such wires where magnetic fields are not canceled out?
If an electron is moving or standing still in an empty space, does it produce magnetic field?

A stationary electric charge has only an electric field but when in motion both an electric and a magnetic field will be observed. Magnetism in this sense is a kinematic/kinetic phenomenon so much so that the "integral" of the magnetic field, the so called vector potential represents the field momentum.

Related 01 : Why don't stationary charge feel force from a current carrying wire?.

Related 02 : Magnetic field due to a single moving charge.

Related 03 : Electric field associated with moving charge.

This might help https://youtu.be/sDlZ-aY9GN4?feature=shared, or confuse you more with some extra concepts

When we say that a current is made of moving charge carriers (like electrons), we mean that the charge carriers are moving relative to some frame. Often, that frame is "us", or more precisely, the lab.
However, all inertial observers must be able to derive the same consequences for electromagnetic phenomena using Maxwell's equations. A moving charge near a wire experiences a magnetic force, but we can surely go into the rest frame of the charge, in which case $v\times B=0$; how can we explain the deflection of the charge in this frame.
In fact, you can find such a frame, where the test charge's is zero. And in this frame, there is no magnetic force. However, while the negative electrons move in the lab frame, the positive ions making up the crystal structure of the wire do not. As a result, when moving into the frame where the current is zero, if one carefully accounts for length contraction, one finds that the electrons and ions contract by different amounts, leading to a net charge density in the wire. This creates an electric field around the wire. This electric field is then responsible for creating an electric force that produces the same physical effect on a test charge, that could also be observed by the test charge interacting with a magnetic field in the lab frame.
This reflects a general phenomena, that electric and magnetic fields themselves are not invariant under boosts -- meaning different inertial observers will disagree about how much electric field there is. However, their combined effect as an electromagnetic field is the same for all inertial observers. You can read more about that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity
In fact, trying to reconcile why different inertial observers would assign different "causes" to electromagnetic phenomena is what led Einstein to special relativity, which is why his famous paper on special relativity is called "On the electrodynamics of moving bodies".

Thanks @Dale for a useful correction to the the original version of this answer.

If an uncharged wire has a current then there is no frame where there is no current. Such a wire has a magnetic field in every frame. $E^2-B^2$ is an invariant. If that is negative then $B\ne 0$

@Dale, even without the Maths: if you are stationary wrt the positive ions and you see electrons moving North you observe a current to the South. If you move with the electrons you see the positive ions move South, so you still observe a current to the South.

yes, you need to correct this answer.May be imagine a wire charged with electrons and without positive ions

@Dale Weirdly enough I knew that which is why I said you couldnt convert a pure magnetic field into a pure electric field, but I misremembered an example from Purcell's textbook which I thought he got away with because he was dealing with an infinite wire. Anyway you're right so I will fix it.

Thank you.
Why then this field is a circular magnetic field and not "outwards" magnetic field? I saw the relativity (length contractions) explanations but I don't get why the shape would get circular. Is there any intuitive explanation for that?
Also, would it mean that by shaking let's say charged comb I wouldn't actually create EM waves because there's no current? Or is changing electric field enough to induce magnetic field? How then it works if in all frames electrons and protons are in the same spot?
